# Does scalatra use circumflex behind the scenes?

Tags: rest, scala, scalatra

Does [scalatra](http://github.com/scalatra/scalatra) use [circumflex](http://github.com/inca/circumflex) behind the scenes (or vise versa)? What are the key differences between them, and which one would you use?

Both frameworks are inspired by [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and from a glance look identical.

Request routing with scalatra:

```
class ScalatraExample extends ScalatraServlet {

get("/date/:year/:month/:day") {
  <ul>
    <li>Year: {params("year")}</li>
    <li>Month: {params("month")}</li>
    <li>Day: {params("day")}</li>
  </ul>
}
```

Sample code in circumflex:

```
class Main extends RequestRouter {

get("/posts/:id") = "Post #" + uri("id")

}
}
```

Comment: They're both inspired by Sinatra, which accounts for the similar structure. They don't seem that similar in some other respects. Circumflex appears to be a lot more elaborate, as it includes features such as an ORM. This is the first time I've heard of Circumflex, actually. I don't know if one was forked from the other. I'm planning on checking it out too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ross A. Baker, one of the Scalatra developers, has recently commented on the difference between Circu,flex and Scalatra:

> They are superficially very similar,
>   though I think each has its strengths.
>   Here are some differences that I see:
>
> Templating: Scalatra integrates with
>   Scalate, Circumflex integrates with
>   Freemarker.
>
> Routing: Circumflex has nicer sugar
>   for header matching, but Scalatra lets
>   you match on arbitrary booleans (i.e.,
>   global flag for site maintenance)
>
> ORM: Circumflex has one, Scalatra
>   doesn’t. I know of Scalatra users
>   using Squeryl, Querulous, Scala-Query,
>   ORMBroker, and, yes, Circumflex-ORM.
>   These integrations are trivial, and I
>   assume would also be trivial with
>   Circumflex.
>
> Auth: Scalatra has an auth module in
>   its latest snapshot, Circumflex does
>   not.
>
> i18n: Circumflex has sugar for message
>   bundles, Scalatra does not.
>
> Testing: Scalatra also includes a nice
>   DSL for testing; I’m not aware of
>   anything similar for Circumflex.